# How can I convert one row of values with panda

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, plot

How can I convert one row of values with panda

```
df = pd.read_csv('blackred.csv')

words = []
for i in df:
    words.append(i)

num = []
```

I want to grab the index 0 column and convert it into a list of numbers and set it to num

How can I do that

This is my csv file I just want to grab 7,21,19,9,2 please let me know how

[csv_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7notp.png)

Comment: You can use `df.iloc[0].tolist()` Read upon [`selection by position`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position)

Answer (score 0):

I understood that *grab the index 0 column* is actually *grab the index 0 column*.

```py
num = df.loc[0].to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.to_list()`.

You will get a list: `[7, 21, 19, 9, 2]`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['black','red','even','odd', 'NONE'], index = [0])
df.loc[0] = [7, 21, 19, 9, 2]

# Grab data in a row into a list
df.loc[0].to_list()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use .iloc and list()

> list(words.iloc[0])